# MVC Convention in Java Swing Application and JavaBeans

Tags: java, model-view-controller, design-patterns, javabeans

I am curious as to if a VIEW class of the MVC convention can retrieve a bean object to change its textual displays. I am not treating the `bean` as my `model`, rather `model` changes the state of the bean which could then be used by `VIEW`. On request, Model would pass an object of Bean to the controller who would then pass it it to Views. Is this bad?

Heres What I mean:
Bean:

```
    public class Bean{

    private String eventName;
    private String eventDate;
    //getters
    //setters

}
```

Model:

```
public class Model {

Bean e = new Bean();
e.setEventOpportunity(rs.getString(7));
        e.setEventMoreDetails(rs.getString(8));
        e.setEndTime(rs.getString(9));



}
```

Control:

```
public class Control () {
public Control() {
Bean events; 
events = model.getEvent(tableClick); //tell model to change its state based on user input on views 
view.changeDisplay(events);
                    }

        }
        }
```

Views:

```
     public class Views {
    public void editTextFields(Bean e) {
       try {
       txtEventName.setText(e.getEventName());
       String dateString = e.getEventDate();


       } catch(Exception te) {
           te.printStackTrace();
       }
   }



    }
```

is such design keep to the mvc convention still. I didnt want my Model to be cumbersome because its dealing with databases and by putting Bean properties in there the class will get cumbersome.

Comment: Where do "Swing" and "sql" come into picture?

Comment: @TechSpellBound I dont know, Views is really made up of swing components, and Model is really dealing with sql concepts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trapped by the MVCs "editor mismatch", i.e. you have an editor/view and a model and the two can't agree what information to expose how. Usually, the [editor/view needs additional information which the model doesn't care about](http://blog.pdark.de/2012/12/19/mvvm-when-mvc-isnt-enough/).

[Model View ViewModel (MVVM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) solves this and the solution is pretty similar to yours.

The only change I suggest is to move the "create Bean" code from the model to the controller. Controllers are meant to configure model, view and view models to play well together.

Comment: hmm struggling to understand why you would do this. This is what I understood from you comment:

1. I should create the bean object in Controller.
2. Get the Model to pass the database information to the Controller
3. using those data obtained in 2, let Controller configure Bean through the setters?

If so, why not model update bean itself, why controller?

Comment: If you let the model create the bean, then the model must know about it. If you add a second view which needs a different bean, you will have to change your model (instead of just writing a new controller). But you should probably find a better way to get data from your model. Consider a convention-over-configuration approach where you pass a Bean into the model and the model uses reflection to determine which values to set in the bean.

Comment: For example, you could use annotations to encode which method of the ResultSet to call, say, `@StringColumn(7)` which should be translated to `rs.getString(7)`

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I think my application is rather simple where a VIEW relates to a respective model through a controller. I dont particularly have 2 or more views requiring the service of A Model and therefore from your explanation I think its best I leave as it is. I do have other views, but theyre completely unrelated set of function that serve different purposes. For example the above was events, I have views for contacts. Contacts and Events are completely different so shouldnt really share the same model